# Java validate and split numbers and symbols using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to validate a String where it MUST have certain pattern in correct sequence, and further splitting them into groups.

My expected format is `\60#######` or `\60000000` where

1. It must starts with only one "\"
2. Follow by one or more Digit (the 60 is example, it can be any number)
3. Follow by zero or more "#"
4. Nothing else behind

Possible matches are like

1. \60000000000
2. \60###
3. \60############
4. \58342##

So I've compiled regex below trying to validate, and further break it into groups (expecting 2 groups (without #) or 3 groups (with #)):

`Pattern numPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\\\{1})|([0-9]+)|(#*)");`

I'm trying to detect 1 x \, 1 or more 0 to 9, any number of #.

And unit test:

```
private static void digest(String formatTxt) {
    System.out.println("Doing: " + formatTxt);
    Pattern numPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\\\{1})|([0-9]+)|(#*)");

    if (numPattern.matcher(formatTxt).find()) {
        System.out.println("Pattern matched!");
    }

    int i = 0;
    Matcher matcher = numPattern.matcher(formatTxt);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        i++;
        String data = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(i + ". " + data);
    }

    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    digest("\\60000000000");
    digest("\\6000000000000");
    digest("\\60#########");
    digest("\\60############");
    digest("\\60############6");
    digest("\\60########A####");
    digest("\\lala60000000000");
    digest("\\60#####6######");
    digest("\\60#####6##A####");
}
```

Result:

```
// Doing: \60000000000
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60000000000
// 3. 
// Comment: OK but not sure why is there third element
// 
// Doing: \6000000000000
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 6000000000000
// 3. 
// Comment: OK but not sure why is there third element
// 
// Doing: \60#########
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60
// 3. #########
// 4. 
// Comment: OK but not sure why is there forth element
// 
// Doing: \60############
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60
// 3. ############
// 4. 
// Comment: OK but not sure why is there forth element
// 
// Doing: \60############6
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60
// 3. ############
// 4. 6
// 5. 
// Comment: Not OK because I do not want anything behind #
// 
// Doing: \60########A####
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60
// 3. ########
// 4. 
// 5. ####
// 6. 
// Comment: Not OK because I do not want anything behind first group of #
// 
// Doing: \lala60000000000
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 
// 3. 
// 4. 
// 5. 
// 6. 60000000000
// 7. 
// Comment: Not OK because \\ must be followed by digits
// 
// Doing: \60#####6######
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60
// 3. #####
// 4. 6
// 5. ######
// 6. 
// Comment: Not OK because I do not want anything behind first group of #
// 
// Doing: \60#####6##A####
// Pattern matched!
// 1. \
// 2. 60
// 3. #####
// 4. 6
// 5. ##
// 6. 
// 7. ####
// 8. 
// Comment: Not OK because I do not want anything behind first group of #
```

Appreciate if anyone could kindly guide me what do I need to alter in the regex so I can achieve the requirement above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(\\)(\d+)(#*)$
```

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6belVt/2)

In Java, you may use `String rx = "(\\\\)(\\d+)(#*)"` with `Matcher.matches`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `matches()`)
- `(\\)` - Group 1: a single backslash
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `(#*)` -  Group 3: 0+ `#` chars
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `matches()`).

Fixed [Java demo code](https://ideone.com/Alqfx0):

```
private static void digest(String formatTxt) {
    System.out.println("Doing: " + formatTxt);
    Pattern numPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\\\)(\\d+)(#*)");
    Matcher m = numPattern.matcher(formatTxt);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Pattern matched!");
        System.out.println("1. " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("2. " + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("3. " + m.group(3));
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Wiktor, but should I include $ sign at the end of the `String rx` as well?

Comment: @ChorWaiChun See my [demo](https://ideone.com/Alqfx0) for the usage details. With `matches()`, leading `^` and trailing `$` are not necessary.

Comment: Just a note: if you are using the regex in a kind of a loop, define it outside the `digest` method, and use a compiled version to initialize each `Matcher`.

Comment: Just wow, that is exactly what I needed, thank you so much for the explanations! =)

Comment: But one question, is it normal that there's always third group?

Comment: @ChorWaiChun You define the number of groups with `(...)`. If you do not need any, just remove the corresponding parentheses. Also, if you want to have the 3rd group as *null*  if it is missing, replace `(#*)` with `(#+)?` (=1 or 0 sequences of 1 or more `#` chars).